# jquery contains() syntax for 'not'?

Tags: jquery, contains

I want to append if the li says "Thing" but NOT if it says "Things". Is that possible with `:contains` ?

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2):contains('Thing')").append("foo");
```

Comment: Do you mean if it contains "Thing" anywhere in the string but not if it contains "Things" anywhere in the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [not function](http://api.jquery.com/not/) :

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2):contains('Thing')").not(':contains("Things")').append("foo");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select the element if that exactly has `Thing` text content, you can use `filter` method:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").filter(function(){
       return $(this).text().trim() === 'Thing'
}).append("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) which helps compressing the code a bit.

So it would be like

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2):contains('Thing'):not(:contains('Things'))").append("foo");
```

A small example in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbLzZ/).